# Internet connection troubles and difficulties on Ubuntu 16.10

Tags: networking, dual-boot, internet, 16.10

## The Premise

I have an HP computer and I created a dual-boot with Windows 10 (originally 8.1) and Ubuntu about nine months ago. The computer itself is a few years old. Everything went smoothly up until about a few months ago, when it started having troubling internet issues. It may have some correlation with me updating it to 16.10, or it may not. Now to the problem: the internet connection is unreliable. This has occurred on every network I've been on, and there a few peculiar things about it.

## The Problem

Firstly, whenever the laptop goes to sleep (or remains idle for a long time), the computer loses a connection. The only thing that seems to get it back on is to restart the computer (which isn't too bad as Ubuntu has a relatively speedy start-up, but it does get quite annoying). This has (so far) happened on every internet connection I've been on, and even a direct wired connection will not work. Only a restart solves the issue. Another odd thing is that, currently, I am writing this question on the laptop in question, but it tells me that I have no connection (clearly, this is untrue). I am by no means an expert with Ubuntu, so I will happily provide any terminal output requests (however, I am somewhat familiar with the terminal and can navigate through directories, and all the simple things). I have done some hunting on the internet and was unable to find any other questions describing a similar problem, so I have asked it here. I also tried installing a different network manager (I believe it was WICD), but it did not seem to work either. This problem only occurs on Ubuntu, it has not occurred on the Windows 10 dual-boot.

## Terminal Outputs

Based on similar (but not the same) questions, I have provided some outputs that come up frequently. I can provide more if necessary.

Output of `lspci -knn | grep Net -A3`

```
09:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8188EE Wireless Network Adapter [10ec:8179] (rev 01)
DeviceName: Focus
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company RTL8188EE mini-PCIe card [103c:197d]
Kernel driver in use: rtl8188ee
```

Output of `iwconfig`

```
enp8s0    no wireless extensions.

wlo1      IEEE 802.11  ESSID:"ATTcXtDhMS"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: 1C:1B:68:E7:51:30   
          Bit Rate=72.2 Mb/s   Tx-Power=20 dBm   
          Retry short limit:7   RTS thr=2347 B   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:off
          Link Quality=54/70  Signal level=-56 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:51   Missed beacon:0

lo        no wireless extensions.
```

Output of `lsusb`

```
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 05c8:0226 Cheng Uei Precision Industry Co., Ltd (Foxlink) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8000 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 3938:1032  
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

I've attempted to be as specific as possible here, I will provide any other needed information if requested. I have some experience in Ubuntu, but I am no wizard (especially with these types of problems). Thank you!